# Run the function "read_rpt" and "read_out" from the "swmmr" packages

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to run the example in the article "swmmr - an R package to interface SWMM". I am able to run swmm with the function `run_swmm()` and read the inp file with `read_inp()`, but when ir try to read the rpt file, it gets an error, saying an input is invalid UTF-8.

```
# assigned the inp file path to the variable inp_path
inp_path <- system.file("extdata", "Example1.inp", package = "swmmr")

# running swmm from R
swmm_files <- run_swmm(inp = inp_path,exec = "C:/Program Files/EPA SWMM 5.2.4 (64-bit)/runswmm.exe")

# reading the inp file. Here I can read the file and get a tibble as result.
inp_object <- read_inp(swmm_files$inp)

# reading the rpt file generated by the run_swmm function
rpt_objetc <- read_rpt(swmm_files$rpt)
```

When I run the `read_rpt()` function I get this error:

[image: run read_rpt error]

I don't know how I can fix the encoding of the rpt file generated by the `run_swmm` function.